# Como puedo abrir un Archivo XML en un datagriedview pero solo muestre elmentos especificos?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Me explico mejor, tengo un trabajo de mi universidad y necesito hacer un tipo factura de compra donde muestre solo los productos que se ingresaron un único día, me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para que me muestre solo los productos de un día en concreto y no todos los productos de todos los días, en leguaje c#

Si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería mucho

adjunto imagen de como me gustaria que quedara[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade el código que has intentado

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si no mostras nada (la pantalla no nos dice nada), la respuesta es elegi solo ese dia...